# React - Filtering Cards based on Selected Value from Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui, filtering

I have a React application where I'm using Material-UI's Autocomplete component to filter a cards based on a selected brand. The cards represent different car models, and I want to filter them when a user selects a brand from the Autocomplete dropdown.

The filter:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

const top100Cars = [
  { label: 'Toyota' },
  { label: 'Ford' },
  { label: 'Chevrolet' },
  { label: 'Tesla' },
  { label: 'Honda' },
  { label: 'BMW' },
  { label: 'Audi' },
  { label: 'Mercedes-Benz' },
  { label: 'Ferrari' },
  { label: 'Porsche' },
  { label: 'Lamborghini' },
  { label: 'Nissan' },
  { label: 'Volkswagen' },
  { label: 'Mazda' },
  { label: 'DeLorean' },
  { label: 'Dodge' },
];


export default function searchBar() {

  const [selectedBrand, setSelectedBrand] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      disablePortal
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Cars}
      value={selectedBrand}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        setSelectedBrand(newValue);
      }}
      sx={{
        width: 254, backgroundColor: 'white', borderRadius: 50,
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Марка"
          size='small'
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

The code of one of the cards:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Link, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Card from '@mui/material/Card';
import CardHeader from '@mui/material/CardHeader';
import CardMedia from '@mui/material/CardMedia';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';
import FormControlLabel from '@mui/material/FormControlLabel';
import FormGroup from '@mui/material/FormGroup';
import IconButton, { IconButtonProps } from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Rating from '@mui/material/Rating';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import LocationOnIcon from './SVGiCON';

type ExpandMoreProps = IconButtonProps & {
  expand: boolean;
};

const ExpandMore = styled((props: ExpandMoreProps) => {
  const { expand, ...other } = props;

  const label = { inputProps: { 'aria-label': 'Checkbox demo' } };

  return <IconButton {...other} />;
})(({ theme, expand }) => ({
  transform: !expand ? 'rotate(0deg)' : 'rotate(180deg)',
  marginLeft: 'auto',
  transition: theme.transitions.create('transform', {
    duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
  }),
}));

type RecipeReviewCardProps = {
  to: string; // Specify the destination when the button is clicked
  // Add any additional props you may need
};

export const RecipeReviewCard: React.FC<RecipeReviewCardProps> = ({ to }) => {
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleExpandClick = () => {
    setExpanded(!expanded);
  };
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    gilad: false,
    jason: false,
    antoine: false,
  });

  const handleChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.checked,
    });
  };

  const { gilad, jason, antoine } = state;

  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<number | null>(2);

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    navigate(to);
  };

  return (
    <Card style={{
      width: '312px', height: '285px', backgroundColor: "gray",
    }}>
      <CardHeader
        title="Ауди, А4"
        subheader="София, София-град"
        // titleTypographyProps={{
        //   fontSize: 22,
        // }}
        subheaderTypographyProps={{
          color: "white",
        }}
        style={{
          textAlign: 'center', fontSize: '1px', marginBottom: '-10px', marginTop: '-9px', color: "white",
        }}
      />
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          {/* Adjust the width and height of the image as needed */}
          <CardMedia
            component="img"
            height="84.28px"
            image="https://images.pexels.com/photos/244212/pexels-photo-244212.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=1"
            style={{ marginLeft: '10px' }}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item
          xs={6}
          sx={{
            width: '43px', top: '6px', left: '245px', height: '17px', // Set the width to 100% or adjust as needed
          }}>
          <Typography style={{
            display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: '20px', fontSize: '14px', color: "white",
          }}>
            <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '10px', width: '15px', height: '15px' }} />
            Дизел
          </Typography>
          <Typography style={{
            display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: '20px', fontSize: '14px', color: "white",
          }}>
            <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '10px', width: '15px', height: '15px' }} />
            Бял
          </Typography>
          <Typography style={{
            display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: '20px', fontSize: '14px', color: "white",
          }}>
            <LocationOnIcon style={{ marginRight: '10px', width: '15px', height: '15px' }} />
            2013 г.
          </Typography>
          <Typography style={{
            display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center', marginLeft: '20px', fontSize: '14px', color: "white",
          }}>
            <LocationOnIcon style={{
              marginRight: '10px', width: '15px', height: '15px', color: "white",
            }} />
            290 000 км
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>

      <FormGroup style={{ marginLeft: '10px', marginTop: '11px' }}>
        <FormControlLabel
          style={{ marginBottom: '-10px', color: "white" }}
          control={
            <Checkbox
              checked={gilad}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="gilad"
              size='small'
              style={{ color: 'white' }} />
          }
          label="Реален пробег"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
          style={{ color: "white" }}
          control={
            <Checkbox checked={jason}
              onChange={handleChange}
              name="jason"
              size='small'
              style={{ color: 'white' }} />
          }
          label="Първи собственик"
        />
      </FormGroup>
      <Typography
        component="legend"
        style={{ marginLeft: "8px", fontSize: '13px', color: "white" }}
      >Рейтинг
      </Typography>

      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={12} style={{ marginLeft: '8px', display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
          <Rating name="read-only" value={value} readOnly size="small" />
          <Link to={to}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="success"
              style={{
                marginLeft: '88px',
                width: '103px',
                height: '24px',
                fontSize: '10px',
                borderRadius: '50px',
              }}
              onClick={handleButtonClick}
            >
              Виж повече
            </Button>
          </Link>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

This below is the container component that contains all of the cards

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import { RecipeReviewCard } from './CardTemplate';


export default function ResponsiveCardContainer() {
  return (
    <Grid container justifyContent="center" spacing={5} marginTop={10} paddingBottom={5}>
      <Grid item>
        <RecipeReviewCard to="/more-info/:id" />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <RecipeReviewCard to="/more-info/:id" />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <RecipeReviewCard to="/more-info/:id" />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <RecipeReviewCard to="/more-info/:id" />
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

main.tsx

```
const DefaultComponent: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {sections.map(({ component, sectionId }) => (
        <SectionContainer key={sectionId} sectionId={sectionId}>
          {component}
        </SectionContainer>
      ))}
      <MultiSearchBar />
      <ResponsiveCardContainer />
    </>
  );
};
```

It looks like this right now:

[image: Here is how it looks right now]

However, the filtering is not working as expected. When I select a brand, the cards are not updating accordingly. This because I don't know how to implement the logic for this.

I know that maybe my existing implementation is not perfect, will appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I litterally had to do the same at work, well first in your car models you have to have a way to know which car model belongs to which car brand, something like id ?
After that, use useEffect hook that rerenders when your selectedBrand state changes and in there filter your state of car models that you loop through to show cards of cars. Keep in mind that you have to have a separate state to hold all car models and one to keep filtered, you render filtered state. Here is example of code below

```
const [carModels,setCarModels] = React.useState();
const [filteredCarModels,setFilteredCarModels] = React.useState();
useEffect(() => {
   const filteredData = carModels.where(x => x.carBrandId == selectedBrand.id);
   setFilteredCarModels(filteredData);
},[selectedBrand])
```

I hope it helps or at least gives you some insights !

Comment: No problem, hope it helped you :)